# Transformation of Variables (Distribution of Absolute value)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, solution-verification, statistical-inference, transformation

I am interested in deriving the distribution for $Y=|X|$ such that $f_X(x) = T |x|,$ $-1< x<2$, $T$ is a constant. I started by finding $T$ and deriving the CDF of $Y$ as follows:

$$\int_{-1}^2 T |x| dx = 2T + \frac{T}{2} =1, \quad \Rightarrow T = \frac25.$$

\begin{align*}
F_Y (Y \le y) = P(|X| \le y) = P(-y \le X \le y) = F_X(y) - F_X(-y)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
F_X(x)  = \int_{-1}^x \frac25 |t| dt 
= \frac{x|x| + 1}{5}
= \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2 + 1}{5}, & -1 \le x \le 1 \\\\
\frac{-x^2 + 1}{5}, & -1 < x \le 1
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}

$$F_X(y) - F_X(-y) = \left(\frac{y|y| + 1}{5} \right) + \left( \frac{y|y| + 1}{5} \right) = \frac{2}{5}y|y| + 1.$$

*I don't trust my work. I need the correct solution. This is self-study question.*

Comment: Please go through the steps again. There are many errors.

Comment: @geetha290krm I think my first line used to have some typos.

Comment: Shouldn't you be considering the case  $0 <x \leq 2T$

Comment: Can you give us a link to the original exercise. I suspect that there is a difference between the pdf of $Y=|X|$ and $f_X(x)$. But maybe I've misunderstood something.

Comment: @Ab2020 Yes, I understood. A picture of the exercise I would prefer. Just to be sure that a supporter does not work on a different exercise. FYI, I'm not online for the whole day